# Accessing static in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I'm having trouble sorting my static directory and linking css files through templates in html pages with django. I keep getting the error "Not Found: /CSS/bootstrap.min.css"

I know this is a problem with how my directory is set up in settings.py but I can't seem to fix the issue. Below is my code for settings.py and layout.html (the page i'm using the call the css file).

layout.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = 'C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Capstone/CapstoneNotespool/capstonenotespool/capstonenotespool/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

[image: file path]

Comment: What if you change `STATIC_URL` to `/static/`?

Comment: Doing this removes the "Not found" error. Output now is "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1 404". However, the test font on the page hasn't changed/has not used formatting in the css file.

Comment: Hm...that sounds better. Without seeing the actual project directory it's a little hard to say. Can you take a screenshot of the tree structure with the file location?

Comment: I've updated the post with the file path

Comment: Thanks. That looks right. Have you run `./manage.py collectstatic`? My company actually keeps our static folder in the top level directory, though. So you may want to try moving it there.

Comment: I moved the folder location to an upper directory and that seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Awesome. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! You just need to add the correct static file directory to your STATICFILES_DIRS.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# STATIC_URL tells django the url path to use for all static files. It 
# doesn't really have anything to do with your file locations on your 
# computer.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # Add this line here.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "capstonenotespool", "static"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You must check again your static url, I think you config be wrong.

Here is answer you looking for.

[Example of tree file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jShi3.png)

And this is my config for this

> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
>
> if DEBUG:
>
> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
>
> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", >"static-only")
>
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", >"media")
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS = (
>           os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
>
> )